# is it OK to have a <section> as sibling to the <main> tag

Tags: html

I'm building a "holy grail layout". Is this appropriate HTML?

```html
<header>My header</header>
<section>My Menu</section>
<main>My Content</main>
<aside>Ads</aside>
<footer>M Footer</footer>
```

I ask because I'm not sure if a `section` can be outside of `main` ?

Comment: A `<section>` must contain a heading. Why don’t you just [validate your HTML](https://html5.validator.nu/)?

Comment: @SebastianSimon why "must"? MDN: [Typically, but not always, sections have a heading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section), specs: [A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element). The validator you have linked says ***Warning**: Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections.*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's certainly valid html and also semantic as long as the section's content comes from some template / is not unique. However, if it's a menu as the content suggests, you may want to use `<nav>` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I think it will end up being a `nav` inside the `section` because there might be other stuff as well in there. Thank you for the answer.